# Couldn't update and Software Center isn't working

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The software center isnot working, I can't open it. I made the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and found the following results ( at the bottom of the results)

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-sso-client-gtk_3.0.2-0ubuntu3_all-deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-ubuntu-sso-client_3.0.2-0ubuntu3_all.deb
E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and still it isnot working. Please help me to get out of this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and remove those pkg's.

I mean in the terminal paste these two lines one by one

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-sso-client-gtk_3.0.2-0ubuntu3_all-deb
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/python-ubuntu-sso-client_3.0.2-0ubuntu3_all.deb
```

Then try again .

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I removed the dpkg's one by one but Still I got the same results when I made the above commands.

Comment: could you provide me the complete log ?

Comment: How can I put the whole log. I tried and it is too long and not possible to post

Comment: ok do the same command by adding at this at the end with quotes . ">> out.txt" paste the content in ubuntu.pastebin.com